# Cannot pass url variable through Campaign Monitor Newsletter Email

Tags: html, newsletter

I doing a newsletter where I need to pass 2 variables, **token** and **email** address to the URL to another website. The problem is that Campaign Monitor makes the URL it into the ShortURL which doesn't work in my situation.

**This is how the URL should look like**

```
http://www.example.com/newsletter/index.cfm?token=yes&email=[email]
```

**This is how my Email Link Looks like**

```
<a style="color:#263269;font-size:30px; font-weight:bold;text-decoration:none" href="http://www.example.com/newsletter/index.cfm?token=yes&email=[email]">YES</a>
```

Please advise me if theirs any alternative solutions for this issue. I cannot seem to find any solutions on the their official website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried passing the values from the form and set action to get.

edit: try using ascii value of ampersand & (amp should be lowercase)

Comment: Yes already tried, its doesn't work. It seems some email clients removes the form from the body of the newsletter.

Answer (score 1):

try removing the "&" and adding `"&amp;"`